# Mobx doesn't re-render React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to follow this [guide](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html) from the documentation. Here are my components:

**Footer**

```js
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import React from 'react';
import FooterViewModel from './footerViewModel';

const viewModel = new FooterViewModel();

const Footer = observer(() => {
    return (
        <footer>
            {viewModel.content}
            <button onClick={viewModel.onClick}>Button</button>
        </footer>
    );
});

export default Footer;
```

**FooterViewModel**

```js
import { action, observable } from 'mobx';

export default class FooterViewModel {
    @observable
    public content = 'asdasdasd';

    @action
    public onClick = (): void => {
        this.content = '234';
        console.log(this.content);
    };
}
```

The field `content` is *observable*, `onClick` is *action*, and `Footer` is `observer`, as they should be. But clicking on the button doesn't call re-rendering of the component. Thus, `content` field is changing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I test your code and the content property changes, https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobx-ctztgu, I don´t see any problem here

Comment: And that is the problem. It's not work for me, and I can't understand why

Comment: Yes, I see the difference, I use import { observer } from 'mobx-react', and you are using observer from mobx-react-lite

Comment: No, I also tried this as well. Nothing really changed

Comment: I updated the example react version, and now it does'n work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs, you need to call [makeAutoObservable](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#makeautoobservable):

```
import { action , makeAutoObservable} from 'mobx';
```

and

```
constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobx-5pjrm9?file=index.js

with the observable decorator:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobx-react-lite-jrzgzf?file=index.js

Comment: The documentation says, I can use `@observable` decorator instead

Comment: But in the examples with mobx-react-lite, they don't use observable decorator, this is weird.

Comment: I also try with the observable decorator and it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobx-react-lite-jrzgzf?file=index.js

Comment: If it still does not work for you, check the versions of the dependencies, it is the only difference between what is working and what you have

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `v6` (and you should) you need to explicitly enable decorators.
Since you are using TypeScript in your `tsconfig.json` you need to enable these compiler options:

`experimentalDecorators : true`

and

`useDefineForClassFields : true`

More information in the [docs](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html#enabling-decorators-)